# Store project reference paths in .csproj, not user file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I altered a bunch of project files in our solution, to add a reference path to all of them. I didn't realize that Reference Paths are stored in the .user file for the project. Is there a way to store those in the .csproj file, so they can be checked into source control?

Comment: The .user file contains debug settings, not references.  You'd better post an example of what you see.

Comment: @Han, in my .csproj.user file, in addition to Publish history, I have <PropertyGroup><ReferencePath>...</ReferencePath><PropertyGroup> as set from the IDE. When I move this to the main .csproj, the reference paths are not picked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try adding the reference as a HintPath, like this:

```
<Reference Include="MyReference, Version=2.0.3.2, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">     
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\Whatever\MyReference.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, just deleting all of the reference paths, deleting the references, and re-adding the references pointing to the new location (which is what sets the HintPath). Thanks :)

Comment: This is useful if you know what reference you are looking for. Having the reference path lets you pull dependencies from the reference path, which you can't quite do from the .csproj (at least I can't)

Answer (score 9):

You can edit the project file by hand and add `<ReferencePath>` inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tags.

The syntax in my case was

```
<ReferencePath>$(Codez)\z.Libraries\AutoCAD\2015;
$(Codez)\z.Libraries\AutoCAD\2015\inc-win32;
$(Codez)\z.Libraries\AutoCAD\2015\inc-x64</ReferencePath>
```

where `$Codez` is an Environment variable I set myself and it obviously supports multiple paths. This is in VS2013.

Comment: This is also useful if you want different reference paths for different build configs

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. HintPaths are pretty useless in a professional environment.